# Display pydoc's description as part of argparse '--help'

Tags: python, argparse, pydoc

I am using **argparse.ArgumentParser()** in my script, I would like to display the pydoc description of my script as part of the '--help' option of the argparse.

One possibly solution can be to use the *`formatter_class`* or the *`description`* attribute of ArgumentParser to configure the displaying of help. But in this case, we need to use the 'pydoc' command internally to fetch the description.

Do we have some other ways (possibly elegant) to do it?

Comment: yaa, `__doc__` is enough for me. Thanks ! Is there any other way instead of using the `formatter_class/description` ?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can retrieve the docstring of your script from the `__doc__` global. To add it to your script's help, you can set the `description` argument of the parser.

```
"""My python script

Script to process a file
"""

p = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__,
                            formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)
p.add_argument('foo', help="Name of file to process")
p.parse_args()
```

Then the help will look like:

```
$ python tmp.py --help
usage: tmp.py [-h] foo

My python script

Script to process a file

positional arguments:
  foo         Name of file to process

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

You can use the `epilog` keyword argument instead of `description` to move the docstring to the end of the help, instead of immediately following the usage string.

Comment: If he has a multiline docstring, the description will merge it into one line. It's better to use `ArgumentParser(usage=__doc__)`

Comment: Oh, right. You would need to set `formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter` to preserve formatting. I'm afraid I'm just duplicating stuff he's already tried, now.

Answer (score 0):

There is an elegant argparse wrapper allowing to use a Python function docstring as a command help in your command line interface: [dsargparse](https://pypi.org/project/dsargparse/)

It does this smartly keeping only the description part of the function docstring not the arguments part that can be irrelevant to your command.

As mentioned in its [Readme](https://github.com/jkawamoto/dsargparse):

> dsargparse is a wrapper of argparse library which prepares helps and descriptions from docstrings. It also sets up functions to be run for each sub command, and provides a helper function which parses args and run a selected command.
>   Using this library, you don't need to write same texts in docstrings, help, and description.